# Python: Attempting to scrape multiple (Similar) websites for (Similar) data

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I have a code that retrieves information from HPEs website regarding switches. The script works just fine and outputs the information into a CSV file. however, now I need to loop the script through 30 different switches.

I have a list of URLs that are stored in a CSV document. Here are a few examples.

```
 https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J4813A
 https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J4903A
 https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9019B
 https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9022A
```

in my code, I bind 'URL' to one of these links, which pushes that through the code to retrieve the information I need.

Here is my full code:

```
url = "https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?
ProductNumber=J9775A"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"})
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 'Current_Releases'}):
    item = []
    for val in row.find_all('td'):
        item.append(val.text.encode('utf8').strip())
    rows.append(item)

with open('c:\source\output_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow({url})
  writer.writerow(headers)
  writer.writerows(rows)
```

I am trying to find the best way to automate this, as this script needs to run at least once a week. It will need to output to 1 CSV file that is overwritten every time. That CSV file then links to my excel sheet as a data source

Please find patience in dealing with my ignorance. I am a novice at Python and I haven't been able to find a solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a linux system? You could set up a cron job to run your script whenever you want.

Comment: Its not a matter of when the script runs, its a matter of getting the script to run with 30 extra URLs instead of just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just make an array of each "ProductNumber" unique query parameter value and iterate through that array via a loop.

Then, by calling the rest of the code as it would be encapsulated in that loop, you should be able to accomplish this task.